# Convert mp4 file with subtitles to compressed gif

Tags: video, ffmpeg, gif, mp4

There is a mp4 file whose size is `1.1 MB`. Now I want to burn in subtitles to it then convert it to `gif`.

Here is my step.

#### First remove audio

As I don't need audio so I remove audio and size changes from `1.1MB` to `784KB`.

```
# remove audio
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -an input_nosound.mp4
```

#### Second resize mp4 file

In order to resize reulst gif, I resize input mp4 file. Now its size changes from `784KB` to `298KB`.

```
# resize
ffmpeg -i input_nosound.mp4 -s 250x150 -c:a copy input_resize.mp4
```

#### Third add subtitles

This step is normal. After that size changes from `298KB` to `290KB`.

```
ffmpeg -i input_resize.mp4 -vf ass=subtitles.ass output.mp4
```

#### Fourth speed up video.

Speeding up video lightly can also reduce size from `290KB` to `247KB`.

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -an  -filter:v "setpts=0.8*PTS" output_speed.mp4
```

#### Firth convert mp4 to gif

I convert mp4 to gif. The size of gif is `3MB`.

```
ffmpeg -y -i output_speed.mp4 -vf palettegen palette.png
ffmpeg -y -i output_speed.mp4 -i palette.png -filter_complex paletteuse -r 8 animation.gif
```

#### Finally compress gif

I use https://github.com/kornelski/giflossy/ to compress gif. Finally the output.gif is `1.5MB`. However I think it's also too large. Is there any acceptable way to compress smaller than `1MB`.

In additional, I am not familiar with `ffmpeg` so if you think my question is not good please tell me.

Comment: Since you don't want sound, I'd suggest trying to reduce the frame rate of the orginal mp4 to make it smaller. You can reduce the frame rate, remove the audio and resize with one command.
Do you want your subtitles added before you resize or after?

Comment: Yes I want to subtitles added before resize.

Comment: Can you reduce the frame rate to make it smaller? If you can.... use  ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf ass=subtitles.ass -r [new frame rate] -an -s 250x150 output.mp4. If not use ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf ass=subtitles.ass -an -s 250x150 output.mp4

Comment: When I convert mp4 to gif , I have set frame rate. So is there need to reduce frame for mp4?

Comment: I would imagine that reducing the frame rate first, should make the file much smaller.